# Not able to login to the mongo shell after creating users

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongodb-query

To apply user management in MongoDb I have created users in admin and other databases. I have created a admin user in both admin db and the other database.

I have authenticated the user by `db.auth()` and started mongod service with

```
mongod --auth
```

The Mongod service have started but now I am not able to login the mongoshell, with the admin any user and password i have created

Comment: can you show your mongodb.conf file ? Did you start your mongod instance using the command: mongod --auth --config /etc/mongodb/mongodb.conf

Comment: Yes I have uncommented the auth in the config file to make it true. Mongod process is running fine. But i am not able to login to the mongoshell with the users i have created. Also, i have created a same user in the admin and the database with admin privileges.